# Adding Texture programmatically to SCNFloor SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I'm trying to add an SCNFloor object to my SCNScene in SceneKit, and after trying many different things, I still can't get a texture or even a color to show up in the floor I've created - the floor shows up black after severa different attempts (see attached screen shot).

Here's the code I've been using, for the simplest case (just adding a color):

```
   let floor = SCNFloor.init()

   floor.reflectivity = 0.3
   floor.reflectionFalloffStart = 0.0
   floor.reflectionFalloffEnd = 3.0
   floor.reflectionResolutionScaleFactor = 0.0

   floor.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

   let floorNode = SCNNode.init(geometry: floor)

   floorNode.position = SCNVector3.init(0.0, -12.0, 0.0)

   self.scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode)
```

I've also tried the following (note that the image below works for any other SCNGeometry):

```
   let material = SCNMaterial.init()

   material.diffuse.contents = UIImage.init(named: "floor1.png")

   floor.materials = [material]
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are there lights in your scene?

Comment: Change the positions of the light sources.

Comment: Nope no lights, guess I'll add some.